# How to add tags/labels to scala metrics, using metrics4-scala + prometheus

Tags: scala, metrics

I am using metrics4-scala and able to get metrics like

```
 Metrics_incrementedCounter_test_count 1.0
```

using below code:

```
  override lazy val metricBaseName = MetricName(s"Metrics")
    private def mName(metricName: String, person: String): String = {
      s"$metricName.$person"
    }
  def incrementedCounter(player: String): Counter = {
      metrics.counter(mName("incrementedCounter", player))
    } 
  incrementedCounter("test").inc()
  incrementedCounter("test22").inc()
```

now what I am trying to get is

```
    Metrics_incrementedCounter_count{person=test} <count>
    Metrics_incrementedCounter_count{person=test22} <count>
```

but getting in prometheus:

```
    Metrics_incrementedCounter_test_count <count> # count of the metrics
    Metrics_incrementedCounter_test22_count <count> # count of the metrics
```

any help would be appreciated. Also please tell if there is any other lib which can be used for this. if so , then please give an example too.
Much thanks!